# Issue on getting straight edge line even with distance and weight set to zero

Tags: javascript, shapes, cytoscape.js

Under cytoscape.js, edge line with both segment-distances and segment-weights set to 0 appears not straight but in a incoherent zig-zag (or taxi) fashion.

The edge is drawn from and to specific area of the nodes (by playing with source-endpoint and target-endpoint). The edge is build strangely (and not straight). if not specifying any value for source-endpoint and target-endpoint, then edge line is straight as expected but my code needs to use source-endpoint and target-endpoint.

If I set 'segment-weights': 0.5, then line is build better but still edge appears with extra point which again seems inconsistent as 'segment-distances' is set to 0. Note that my code uses curve-style as 'segments' as well as segment-distances and segment-weights, so i have to set these specific values.

With the below code, see output which shows edge line not perfectly straight :
[image]

if changing segment-weights as 0.5 then I got the output. Why as distance is to 0:
[image]

Did I made a mistake on my code?

What is the change I need to make to make edge line appearing straight?

My code is shown below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Tool</title>
        <meta charset=utf-8 />
        <script src="cytoscape.min.js"></script>
    <style> 
    body { 
      font: 14px helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    }

    #cy {
      height: 90%;
      width: 65%;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 1;
      background-color: WHITESMOKE;
      border: 5px solid #ddd;
      overflow: auto !important;
      border-radius: 1.25em;
    }   
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
            <div id="cy"></div>
        <script>
    var dataOpticalMap =
    {
      "nodes": [
             {
              "data": {"id":"44", "name":"C"},
              "position": {"x":729, "y":-25}
             },
             {
              "data": {"id":"84", "name":"A"},
              "position": {"x":729, "y":75}
             },
      ],
      "edges": [
             {
              "data": {"id":"96", "source":"84", "target":"44" },
             },
        ]
    }

    var cy = cytoscape({
      container: document.getElementById('cy'),
      style: cytoscape.stylesheet()

        .selector('node')       //Generic style applied for each node irrespective of their type
          .css({
            'content': 'data(name)',
            'text-valign': 'center',
            'width': 80,
            'height': 30,
            'shape': 'barrel',
          })
        .selector('edge')       //Generic style applied for each edge
          .css({
            'curve-style': 'segments',
            'edge-distances': 'node-position',
            'segment-distances' : 0,
            'segment-weights': 0,
            'source-endpoint' : "25% -50%",
            'target-endpoint': "25% 50%",
          }),

      elements: {      
      nodes:dataOpticalMap.nodes, 
      edges:dataOpticalMap.edges
      },
        autolock:false,
      layout: {
        name: 'preset',
        directed: true,
        fit: true
      }
    });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I recommend drawing out on paper what each of the property values mean for your example.  Draw out the axes of the co-ordinate system mentioned in the docs, and draw out your points accordingly.  You'll see that your segment point is incorrect for what you want.  It would be great if you would then share your figure and findings as an answer to this question to benefit the community.

Comment: I found something interesting. When manipulating source-point and target-point (ie ("50% -50%") and ("50% -50%") respectively) and '0' for segment-distances and segment-weights, line is not anymore straight.
This is a strange behaviour in cytoscape.js (hopefully not a bug though).

When both segment-distances and segment-weights aren’t define, you’d expect to get a straight line (without any bending), but line actually transits through the middle of the source node and then up to target node, making the line not straight anymore but bended. Strange behaviour !

Comment: Other weird behaviour is that cytoscape.js automatically sets by default 'segment-distances' to 20px and 'segment-weights' to 0.5. Why that ? 
To force the line to be straight, then I had to use ele.segmentPoints() which provides an array of coordinates of the bend points of the line. Then I calculate the distance to correct the deviation by using a specific function. This value is added to the default 'segment-distances' (20px) to get the correct deviation to be applied.
A bit scary but it works.

Is this behaviour normal or did I not correctly set the parameters (which could be true) ?

Answer (score 0):

I read maxkfranz's comments but cannot find a suitable and logic answer to my problem.

On my example both source-endpoint and target-endpoint are defined in percentage and corresponds to a position within the node. I have indicated in the below picture some example of position coordinate :

[image]

On my code above, position of source-point (ie "25% -50%") is located in first red point on top line of the node. Same logic for target-point.

If setting source-point as ("0% -50%") and target-point as ("0% 50%") and keeping :          'segment-distances' : 0,
'segment-weights': 0
then, system draws perfectly a straight vertical line as expected :

But when manipulating source-point and target-point (ie ("50% -50%") and ("50% -50%") respectively) and '0' for segment-distances and segment-weights, line is not anymore straight :

[image: <picture>]

now if removing properties of segment-distances and segment-weights, then line appears with a deviation, see below. It should actually draw a vertical straight line.

[image]